# SQLite How To - Sum by Value in a JOIN

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have a sample sqlite database that currently has 7 entries which is queried via:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TRANSACTIONS + " x " +
                     "JOIN (SELECT " + KEY_TYPE_ID + ", COUNT(*) count FROM " + TABLE_TRANSACTIONS + " GROUP BY " + KEY_TYPE_ID + " ORDER BY count DESC) y " +
                     "ON x.type_id = y.type_id " + //type_id  vs. KEY_TYPE_ID as alias won't recognize KEY_TYPE_ID
                     "WHERE x.type_id = " + TagData.TYPE_EXPENSE;
```

The output is:

```
Type A = 2500
Type A = 2599
Type B = 45000
Type C = 299
Type C = 2699
Type C = 10000
Type C = 12000
```

which correctly groups my types by their respective values. However, the ideal output would be:

```
Type B = 45000
Type C = 24998
Type A = 5099
```

where each type is then ordered by the sum of each type. Is this possible? If so what else should I be doing in my query? I'm relatively new to SQL and haven't been able to figure this out yet. Thank you in advance for any insight.

*EDIT*

Based on your input @CL. I now have a more simplified query:

```
        String selectQuery = "SELECT *, SUM(" + KEY_AMOUNT + ") AS amount_sum " + 
                         "FROM " + TABLE_TRANSACTIONS + " " +
                         "GROUP BY " + KEY_LABEL_ID + " " +
                         "ORDER BY amount_sum DESC";
```

which works as expected when I use sqlfiddle at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b3615/1 but not when I use the query in Android. In Android, only the most recent entry for each label type is returned. The SUM doesn't seem to actually do its job.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CL. Your response led me down the correct path, for those interested here is the resulting query that achieved what I was after:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_LABEL_ID + ", " + " SUM(" + KEY_AMOUNT + ") as total, " + KEY_TYPE_ID + " " +
                         "FROM (" +
                                    "SELECT " + KEY_LABEL_ID + ", " + KEY_AMOUNT  + ", " + KEY_TYPE_ID + " " +
                                    "FROM " + TABLE_TRANSACTIONS + " " +
                                ") as trans_table " +
                         "WHERE " + KEY_TYPE_ID + " = " + TagData.TYPE_EXPENSE + "  " + 
                         "GROUP BY " + KEY_LABEL_ID + " " +                     
                         "ORDER BY total DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving the aggregation and ordering into a subquery does not make sense.

If you want to get the count of all expense transactions per type, just use a simple aggregation:

```sql
SELECT Type_ID,
       COUNT(*) count
FROM TRANSACTIONS
WHERE TYPE_IF = 'TYPE_EXPENSE'
GROUP BY TYPE_ID
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an aggregation query.  Fortunately, SQLite supports CTEs, so you can just do something like this:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select type, sum(value) as sumv
from t
group by type
order by sumv desc;
```

Even without the `with` clause, you could just use your query as a subquery.

You would, of course, use the appropriate column names in the query.

Comment: Most Androids do not have an SQLite version supporting CTEs.

Comment: @CL . . . Then the OP can use a subquery, as I mention in the answer.